# Enabling a timer when a button is pressed C#

Tags: c#, button, timer

I have two forms, form1 and form2. In form1 I have a button which, when pressed, will make form2 appear. In form2 I have a button which will enable a Timer control. The problem is that the timer is already enabled when form2 appears, even if I did not press the button yet.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3):

Set the Enabled - property of the timer to false by default, and set it to true when the button in Form2 is pressed.

**Update:**

You can do this in the Properties windows in the Designer of your form or you can do this through code, like this:

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer1.Enabled = false;
}

//And in the button-event: timer1.Enabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Timer's `Enabled` property to `false` at the design time